# Wireshark Output | [Malformed Packet: Laplink: length of contained item exceeds length of containing item] from Russian IP

Tags: network, buffer-overflow, wireshark, packet

While running some traces for one of our production servers, an interesting item kept popping up in our Wireshark:

> [Malformed Packet: Laplink: length of contained item exceeds length of containing item]

This is consistently coming from a single source IP. When I geomap it, the IP sources from `Zhigulevsk Cable Network LLC` in Russia.

The only information I can find on "laplink" is the PC mover software: https://web.laplink.com/

Is there precedent for this sort of thing being used as part of an attack? Should we be concerned or should we just block the IP and move along about our day?

Comment: It's probably a packet that is not Laplink but Wireshark is trying to decode as if it was. Every computer on the Internet receives all kinds of random packets all the time - yes, from scanners. If you are not vulnerable to the attack why even bother to block it?